# Unable to update content or enable / disable module via Drupal Admin once migrate to live server

Tags: nodes, users, .htaccess

I have moved my website from local machine to live server, but after migration I can not save or update contents. After clicking on 'Save' button page refreshes without any changes. Also I can not enable or disable the drupal modules, and there aren't any errors displayed. Please help me out in this and do let me know solution in isolating this issue.

Comment: Check mod rewrite and check if .htaccess was uploaded or not

Comment: thanks for reply Nikunj Kotecha. .htaccess file is there and mod rewrite is on

Comment: can you share your live url? also check if normal post in any .php file is working?

Comment: please check it here http://dhalahore.edu.pk/ i thought that i can not make changes in database but then i clear the cache and it worked but when i try to add content its just simply refreshing the page without creating any new content

Comment: able to send message in contact page, there must be some issue in code or check the PHP versions in local and server

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.15 and on server PHP Version 5.4.45

Comment: i have updated the php version to 5.5.15 on the server but still problem is there.. any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1):

problem was server firewall called mod_security. It's purpose is to stop hackers from inserting mysql_query type commands into your website. So, I solved this problem by disabling the mod_security service.

Comment: glad to know a different kind of problem